# Empty data on simple query in Grafana. Table works ok

Tags: grafana

I need to use Grafana for simple db queries to show some basic ERP data.

My MS SQL query is very simple:

```
select "Production Line", "Pallets" from vLiveProduction order by Plant, "Production Line"
```

The data are pretty straight forward and they display in a table.

[image]

I cant make them display in a graph or bar or any plugin i tried to.

I must be doing something fundamentally wrong here but i cant see what. Any help?

I AM choosing series in graph but nothing changes. I cant find a way to tell Grafana which column is the series and which the value… Tried by naming my columns metric and value but still no luck.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use the bar guage panel in Grafana > 6.2.

You can change the config so that Display = All Values. which i think will give you what you want! Plus the Retro LCD setting under Mode looks cool :)

Tom